# Example of a function $f$ where $δ=δ(x)$ can be computed analytically in terms of $x$.

Tags: real-analysis

If a real function $f:ℝ→ℝ$ is twice differentiable at a point $x$, then the first derivative must be continuous at $x$, and assuming $f′(x)>0$, then there exist $δ>0$ such that $f′(y)>0 $ for all $y∈(x−δ,x+δ)$, then on this interval $f$ must be increasing. Repeating this process for all $x$, we conclude that $δ$ is a function of $x$.

I am asking if it is possible to find an example of a **nonlinear** function $f$ where $δ=δ(x)$ (the largest such radius) can be computed analytically in terms of $x$.

Comment: For definiteness you probably want to specify $\delta(x)$ to be the *largest* such radius.

Comment: @DavidKraemer: Yes. This is what I am looking for.

Comment: $f(x)=x^2; \delta(x)=|x|$

Comment: Then $\delta(x)$ is just the distance to the closest zero of $f'$.

Comment: minor note: the "largest" $\delta$ need not exist (as a real number). For example, take $f(x) = e^x$. Then, $\delta(x) = \infty$ for all $x \in \Bbb R.$

Comment: The definition is unclear to me. Is $\delta$ the largest positive number such that $f$ is strictly increasing on $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ or such that $f'>0$ on $(x-\delta,x+\delta)?$ And if no positive $\delta$ works at $x$ do we define $\delta (x)=0?$